# How to remove the dynamically appearing scroll?

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

There is a header and a form after it. When an error text appears in the form, the height of the form's container gets bigger and a scroll appears. Is there any way to make the scroll not appear when the height increases?

```
// Header - not scrollable
// Form - not scrollable
// Main content (search results) - scrollable

<header className='sticky top-0 z-[1000]'>
  <div className='flex items-center mx-auto max-w-content min-h-[50px] tablet:pl-10'>
    <div className='w-[80px] max-h-6 md:w-[100px]' />
    <img src ='…'>
        </div>
</header>

<div className='relative flex z-[1000] mx-auto w-full'>
  <div className='flex w-full max-w-content my-0 mx-auto pt-2 px-5'>
     /// form
  </div>
</div>

// main content
```

Comment: Hello, can you create a reproducible example so we can help you? It's very difficult to understand and help you without the actual issue.

Answer (score 0):

Of course.
There is a way what you can fix the mistake.

You can insert the `overflow: hidden` CSS attribute to the styles where is making the scroll, like this.

```html
form  {
  // your styles
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Hope you success in business. regards